# import all csv files in directory as pandas dfs and name them as csv filenames

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to write a script that will import all .csv files in a directory to my workspace as dataframes. Each dataframe should be named as the csv file (minus the extension: .csv).

This is what i have so far, but struggling to understand how to assign the correct name to the dataframe in the loop. I've seen posts that suggest using `exec()` but this does not seem like a great solution.

```
path = "../3_Data/Benefits"                     # dir path
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv")) #make list of paths

for file in all_files:
    dfn = file.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0] # create string for df name
    dfn = pd.read_csv(file,skiprows=5) # This line should assign to the value stored in dfn
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what about saving your DFs as a dictionary of DFs, where keys would be named as you wish?

Comment: I think @MaxU's solution is the best as it allows your to specify variable names without explicitly defining a variable

Comment: Thanks @MaxU, i did want each of the dfs to be accessible directly, but will use dictionary as suggested for now.

Answer (score 8):

`DataFrame` have no `name` their index can have a `name`. This is how to set it.

```
import glob
import os

path = "./data/"
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv")) #make list of paths

for file in all_files:
    # Getting the file name without extension
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
    # Reading the file content to create a DataFrame
    dfn = pd.read_csv(file)
    # Setting the file name (without extension) as the index name
    dfn.index.name = file_name

# Example showing the Name in the print output

#      FirstYear  LastYear
# Name                     
# 0         1990      2007
# 1         2001      2001
# 2         2001      2008
```