# Importing all .csv files within a specified directory into separate arrays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import

I am trying to import all .csv files within a directory. I would like to store them in array for each file (for example named as file_name). I tried following code as suggested in thread [import all csv files in directory as pandas dfs and name them as csv filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058133/import-all-csv-files-in-directory-as-pandas-dfs-and-name-them-as-csv-filenames):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = "E:\\9sem\\INO\\Dane\\input\\"
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv")) #make list of paths

for file in all_files:
    # Getting the file name without extension
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
    # Reading the file content to create a DataFrame
    dfn = pd.read_csv(file)
    # Setting the file name (without extension) as the index name
    dfn.index.name = file_name
```

And I am stuck. I imported the data into single DataFrame but I dont know how to convert it do separate numpy arrays.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Best regards,
Maks

Comment: add all dfn inside the loop into a list? or a dict using the file name as key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would always overwrite the dataframe by the data of the next csv, right?

So either you could use `pandas.concat` to make one big dataframe, or you could store the data in a dictionary. If you want to store it in a dictionary, you could change your code like this:

```
df_dict= dict()
for file in all_files:
    # Getting the file name without extension
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
    # Reading the file content to create a DataFrame
    df_dict[file_name]= pd.read_csv(file)
    # Setting the file name (without extension) as the index name
    df_dict[file_name].index.name = file_name
```

Then you can get the dataframe by `df_dict[base_name]`. Where `base_name` is the name of the source file of the dataframe.

Comment: It was the just thing I need. Thank you and Patrick Artner both, I totally forgot about dictionaries